# How do I get my friend elected mayor?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I really dislike the current mayor of Genoa and would like to replace him with a friend of mine. So I revoked his title, but I am having a bit of trouble making my courtier the new mayor. If as a king I own an entire county, it used to be possible to simply grant some courtier a city title inside that county and that would automatically make them a mayor of the city (which could be used to create vassal merchant republics). I own the county of Genoa now, the City of Genoa is the capital holding, and all other holdings in the county are owned by vassals.

Now when I take a friend of mine from my court and attempt to grant him the county, he does not become a mayor. Instead, he becomes a count (suffering from a wrong demesne holding type penalty). I am not sure when this was changed, but how does one create a vassal merchant republic in this case (without suffering any penalties)?

Comment: What happens when you give him a duchy?

Comment: He becomes a regular feudal duke with his main holding being a city...

Comment: Has this courtier friend of yours ever held any titles before?

Comment: No, he's a lowborn courtier

Comment: Do you have any other merchant republics in your realm?  I've run into the same issue and assumed there was an upper limit on merchant republics per realm (I had 4 others at the time).

Comment: No, this would be my first merchant republic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. Probably easiest way would be to grant your friend a barony level city holding anywhere in your realm. If you don't have one in your demense already you'll need to obtain one. You can revoke the title, build a new city holding or gain it from conquest. Making him a mayor will turn him into burgher. When you grant him the county of Genoa, he'll remain a burgher  making him the lord mayor of Genoa.

If that's not an option, another method would be to somehow acquire another holding in the county of Genoa, but in this case it can be of any type. It doesn't have to be city. To do this, you can build another holding, revoke a title or try to obtain a barony by inheritance. Once you have it, switch the county capital to that holding and then make your friend the mayor of city of Genoa. Grant him the county and he'll be lord mayor of Genoa.

To make your friend doge of a merchant republic you'll need to go one step further and grant him a duchy.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, that there is no way of doing this other than acquiring another city holding.

Comment: @SMeznaric With the second option the holding doesn't have to be a city, it just needs to be in Genoa. A possible third option I'm not sure would work would be to grant the county to someone who's already a major, wait 10 years, revoke the title and then grant the grant city to your friend. The basic problem is that county is a noble title right now, so if you give it to a courtier it will remain a noble title.

Comment: So in my last save the county is actually a mayoral title already, but I want to change the culture of the mayor to my culture (this is my ultimate goal). But if I revoke the county then I only own the city of Genoa together with the county title which is now primary.

Comment: @SMeznaric Looks like my third suggestion won't work then. If culture is your ultimate goal then maybe it would be better to just give the county to your friend, hope he can convert the culture, and meanwhile find some other coastal city that is already your culture to turn into a republic.

Answer (score 2):

Give your vassal the city title first, then give him the county title.

When you give a previously unlanded courtier a county, he becomes a noble-type ruler by default (a count). Only a character who is already a burgher-type ruler through obtaining a mayor-title will become a lord-mayor when obtaining a county.

Comment: I only own one holding in Genoa, the city, so can only grant the whole country without revocations

Comment: @SMeznaric When this is true, you should own both the "*City* of Genoa" title and the "*County* of Genoa" title. These are completely separate titles. A character can own one without owning the other. You *should* be able to grant either to him. Unless your vassal already is landed with a noble-type title or is for some reason not elligible for holding the city title. When you don't own the "*County* of Genoa" title, then who is?

Comment: ...or maybe you only revoked the *Grand-Mayor of Genoa* title (the whole *County* of Genoa) but not the actual *City* of Genoa so the original guy (or someone completely different) is still owning the *City*?

Comment: I own city and county, but city is the only title I own there. Ie I don't own any baronies there.

Comment: @SMeznaric In that case you *should* be able to give away the city-title first making him a mayor and afterwards give the same character the county-title making him a lord-mayor. When you can't give him the city-title then... I have no idea what's wrong, sorry.

Comment: The city title doesn't show up as it's the primary holding in the county. You can't give away the primary holding without the county.

Comment: Maybe there is no way to do this anymore except to also revoke a barony in the county, then giving the city to my courtier, then granting him the county. Seems ridiculous that I have to revoke a barony in order to grant a mayoral title though...